# What is the "recursive moral hazard theory" of "trade credit"?

Tags: theory

When reading a **[recently published paper](http://gofman.info/TC/Trade_Credit.pdf)**, I saw the paragraph

> We construct a sample of over 200,000 supply chains to conduct a
> chain-based analysis of trade credit. Our study uncovers novel
> stylized facts about trade credit both within and across supply
> chains. More upstream firms borrow more from suppliers, lend more to
> customers, and hold more net trade credit. This upstreamness effect in
> trade credit is weaker for more profitable firms and for longer
> chains. Firms in more central or more profitable chains provide more
> net trade credit. Our results are generally consistent with the
> **recursive moral hazard theory of trade credit**. Evidence for the
> **financing advantage theory** is mixed.

Can I ask what does "**recursive moral hazard theory of trade credit**" and what is "**financing advantage theory**"?

The short description here is still ambiguous to me about the meaning

> The recursive moral hazard theory of trade credit describes a steady
> state equilibrium of incentives along the supply chain

Comment: Have you looked at the references? The recursive moral hazard theory of trade credit seems to refer to a 2012 paper by Kim and Shin.

Comment: For financing advantage theory, there seem to be more papers starting with a 1974 paper by Schwartz.